# Service Program that programmatically restarts all the crashed Services

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, service

C++ windows Service Program which should monitor all services and restart them when they crash. 
Any idea how to identify whether the services has crashed or properly stopped ?
which winapi can be used ?

Comment: Is this a todo list, statement or question?

Comment: look for errors in the event log when the service stops

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Search for *Windows service watchdog*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Service Control Manager can detect a failed (correctly written) service, i.e. the death of a service process without it having returned a `SERVICE_STOPPED` status or a `SERVICE_STOPPED` status with a `SERVICE_STATUS` containing a win32 error code -  this is what the *Recovery* tab does.

You can access this programmatically via the `ChangeServiceConfig2()` + `SERVICE_CONFIG_FAILURE_ACTIONS` and then configure it via `SERVICE_FAILURE_ACTIONS` to say execute an external process.

Comment: yes, I got the code from msdn  [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681988(v=vs.85).aspx), Mainly read the ** bold** remarks part

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in mechanism in the Windows to determine service termination reason. `SCM` will report an error if service is unable to start, however if service has been started - any failure reporting is its own business. So if service has been terminated due to the internal errors, killed through the Task Manager, or stopped wia `SCM` - it will have the same status `Service stopped`. If services you are trying to monitor has no error/status reporting mechanism, you will be unable to determine its termination reasons.

Comment: would dwServiceSpecificExitCode of SERVICE_STATUS structure have any info of determining whether service is crashed or not

Comment: Its for errors on server startup/stop if `ERROR_SERVICE_SPECIFIC_ERROR` has been set in `dwWin32ExitCode`. It has no meaning if service started successfully and then failed because of AV, or has been killed by the user.